# WPF DataGrid programmatically add complex columns

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to add columns to my DataGrid programmatically as they're not known until run-time. I've got most of the way there and adding a "normal" column from the code behind isn't a problem. However the column I'm trying to add now has a DataTemplate. Here's the XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding colHeader}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="{Binding BorderColour}" BorderThickness="2">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextInfo}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Normally I'd use something like this to create a column to add to the grid:

```
Private Function AddColumn(colHeader As String, colBinding As String) As DataGridColumn
    Dim textColumn As New DataGridTextColumn()
    textColumn.Header = colHeader
    textColumn.Binding = New Binding(colBinding)
    Return textColumn
End Sub
```

But I'm stumped as to how to add the more complex XAML. Any suggestions?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the DataTemplate of your column in a resource dictionary with a `x:Key` property then access it in your code behind to set your cell template.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="your_data_template">
    <Border BorderBrush="{Binding BorderColour}" BorderThickness="2">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextInfo}" />
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then in the code behind

```
textColumn.CellTemplate = Application.Current.FindResource("your_data_template") as DataTemplate
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scmorris/archive/2008/04/14/defining-silverlight-datagrid-columns-at-runtime.aspx

Code snippet is from above link:(this is one way of doing that.Otherway is also explained in that link)

Xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<local:DateTimeConverter x:Key="DateConverter" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="myCellTemplate">
    <TextBlock 
        Text="{Binding Birthday, 
        Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" 
        Margin="4"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="myCellEditingTemplate">
    <basics:DatePicker 
        SelectedDate="{Binding Birthday, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Code Behind:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
templateColumn.Header = "Birthday";
templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["myCellTemplate"];
templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate = 
                   (DataTemplate)Resources["myCellEditingTemplate"];
targetDataGrid.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
```

Comment: What's the point of giving the exact same answer as mine ? If you wanted to give the link (which is interresting), a simple comment on my answer was enough.